# Marginal probability of Y at a point

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, marginal-distribution

> A car vendor sells type A and type B cars. Consider that X and Y
> represent the types A and B of cars being sold (respectively).
> Consider the Random Pair (X, Y) to have probability function according to the table:

| X/Y | 0 | 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | .1 | .075 | .25 |
| 1 | .1583 | .1 | .5 |
| 2 | .075 | .1583 | .1 |

> What is the value for the marginal distribution function of Y at the point 1.86?

I'm having trouble understanding this.
If I add accumulative values for Y marginal probability I end up with $Y_1 = .33, Y_2 = .43, Y = .33$. First of all, it does not add up to 1. But even then, how do I find the value of the marginal probability at a point that is not in the table? How do I extrapolate the marginal function correctly in order to get its value at 1.86?

Comment: You are right to be confused. I teach a probability class covering this material and I am also confused. (My best guess: the question asks for the marginal *cumulative* distribution function of $Y$, which is $\Pr[Y \le 1.86]$. But that doesn't explain the probabilities that don't add up to $1$.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov how could I get P(Y < 1.86) if I only have P(Y < 0, 1, 2)? Because I don't have the function expression, only discrete values of Y.

Comment: If $Y$ can *only* be $0$, $1$, or $2$, then $\Pr[Y \le 1.86]$ is the same as $\Pr[Y \le 1]$.